# jquery.validate 1.9.0 and jquery.validate.unobtrusive doesnt work with lates version of jquery 1.9.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

jquery.validate 1.9.0 and jquery.validate.unobtrusive doesnt work with lates version of jquery 1.9.1 and the lates version of jquery 1.9.1 is necessary to jquery UI widgets in my MVC4 application someone has the same problem.?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve, just download jquery.validate lastes version..